# Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, state

Full error image:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuFRm.png)

I am making a fetch request and when I want to set the state to save some errors that happens. How do I fix this?

Code:

```
    onClickLogIn = (username, password) => {
    const request = fetch('[SOMEAPILINK]', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'text/javascript',
        'Content-Type': 'text/javascript',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password,
        login: 1
    })
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(responseJson => {   
        console.log(responseJson)
        this.setState({
            errorCheck: responseJson.error
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("error")
    })
    // console.log(errorCheck);
    console.log(request); 
    console.log("----ERROR CHECK ----")
    console.log(this.state.errorCheck)
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")

}
```

So when I want to set errorCheck that error comes in...

Thanks!

Comment: What i understood is, you are working on a login Screen and making API call to check the Credentials. If Api response is success you  will navigate to second screen else you will set the Error to state and Display it. Is that so?

Comment: Yes that is correct, question has been answered correctly already tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
then(response => response.json()).then(responseJson => {   
    console.log(responseJson)
    this.setState({
        errorCheck: responseJson.error
    })
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")
})
```

=>  Add this code `this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")` of navigation inside the `then()` method so it will call navigation after updating the `state` then your error will gone.

=> and try to update the `state` using `setState` **function** not an **object** so try

```
    this.setState(function (prevState, props) {
        return { errorCheck: responseJson.error}
    })
```

it will reduce the time , taken by the object to update the state.

=> So your code will look like

```
  then(response => response.json()).then(responseJson => {   
    console.log(responseJson)
    this.setState(function (prevState, props) {
        return { errorCheck: responseJson.error}
    })
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")
})
```

Comment: I know I am not supposed to write thank you comments but you are a life saver!

Comment: I did but I don't have 15 reputation so it doesn't show on screen.

Comment: How does it make sure the `navigate` function is called after the state is updated? You have no guarantee of that? https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710 @JayThummar.

Comment: Yes there is no  guarantee  that's why i suggest to update state using function .. so it update quickly.   And if we talk about this particular question Luka write the code of navigation out side the response check so this will call the navigation first and after the response will come and call setSate and at that time the component is not in the foreground so the error of unmounted component occurs.

Answer (score 3):

`setState` is asynchronous. So if you unmount the stateful component (by calling navigate) before updating the state then you'll get the warning.

You should use the callback that `setState` provides instead

```
.then(response => response.json()).then(responseJson => {   
        console.log(responseJson)
        this.setState({
            errorCheck: responseJson.error
        }, () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")
        })

})
```